# Is it possible to have all of a controller's actions go into the action cache without specifying each action to caches_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I've got a controller for semi-static pages (the only content that changes is a login/logout link and the presence/absence of a link to the user's home), and I'd like to put the static content into the action cache for every action.

Is there a way to specify to cache all of the pages, without having to manually add each page?

I.e., instead of:

caches_action :foo
caches_action :bar
caches_action :baz

to just specify something like

caches_actions #automatically picks up any newly added action?

The static content are all stored in separate views, but none of them have corresponding methods (b/c there's no work to do - the dynamic content is handled in a before filter and only touched by a layout).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
map.cacher '*path', :controller => :application, :action => :cacher
```